# Threads for variables initialized in loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'd like to run method *Polygonise* parallel for cells (they are independent). 
How to create threads for cells if it is initialized in loop?

```
  for (int j = 0; j < RowCount - 1; j++)
  {
      for (int k = 0; k < ColumnCount - 1; k++)
      {
          GridCell currentCell = GetCurrentCell (Slice1, Slice2, j, k);
          Polygonise (ref Triangles, int isoLevel, GridCell currentCell);
      }
  }
```

**ADDED**: I wish to pass it to GPU thus Parallel.For and PLinq aren't appropriate. The problem is: it performs a long while because there are many computations in *Poligonise* method and there are many rows and columns (loop params). The operations in the method are nearly fast, but the loop for this is time-consuming. I need logic of multithreading in this.

Comment: `Parallel.For`? Parallel Linq (*Plinq*)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I wish to pass it to GPU with Cudafy thus Parallel.For and PLinq aren't appropriate. The problem is to make parallel (probably) architecture for loop with calculations. It performs a long while because there are many computations in Poligonise method.

Comment: I mean I need logic of multithreading appropriate here

Comment: @JuliaGrabovska Which library / method will yo use to pass this to the GPU, and in what fashion? I think the most appropriate answer hinges on how you'll do that.

Comment: If you want to use GPU (say, Cudafy, https://cudafy.codeplex.com/) you have to implement `Polygonise` on GPU: you pass the grid (or part of it) to GPU, perform `Polygonise` on GPU and read the results back. Implementing `Polygonise` on GPU can well be the main trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You can try either `Parallel`s:

```
Parallel.For(0, RowCount, (j) => 
{
    for (int k = 0; k < ColumnCount - 1; k++)
    {
        GridCell currentCell = GetCurrentCell (Slice1, Slice2, j, k);
        // Beware! Possible race condition: 
        // "ref Triangles" is shared reference between threads. 
        Polygonise (ref Triangles, int isoLevel, GridCell currentCell);
    }   
});
```

or *PLinq* (Parallel Linq):

```
Enumerable
  .Range(0, RowCount)
  .AsParallel()
  // .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4) // <- if you want to tune PLinq
  .ForAll(j => {
       for (int k = 0; k < ColumnCount - 1; k++)
       {
           GridCell currentCell = GetCurrentCell (Slice1, Slice2, j, k);
           // Beware! Possible race condition: 
           // "ref Triangles" is shared reference between threads. 
           Polygonise (ref Triangles, int isoLevel, GridCell currentCell);
       } 
   });
```

In both cases, please, think over which should be parallelized `Columns` or `Rows`

Comment: Bad example, because you start parallel only part of 'Polygonise' methods.

Comment: @Ivan Kishchenko: too many threads (e.g. a thread per cell) often mean a great *overhead*; Since CPU has limited number of cores (`2-32`) a better policy is to create/get from pull a *limited* number of threads (e.g. a thread per Row, or per Column). Do not *overparallelize*. GPU (e.g. NVidia `Cuda`) is the exception (GPUs often have 1000+ cores)

Comment: Modern processors are able to effectively parallelize tasks. Please open tasks manager and see how many processes. And how many threads contains any process?

Comment: @Ivan Kishchenko: almost all of these threads are waiting; starting a thread for a task is a common practice (task parallel) - spell cheker has its own thread, internet updates checker its own etc. But you proposed too many simultaneously working threads which is a bad design. Imagine that we have to perform 100x100 grid - 10000 threads? And each of the thread has 1-8 MB stack (x86-IA64)

Comment: I suggested using 'Tasks' instead of 'Threads'. 'Tasks' mechanism start only effective count of 'Threads", while the rest will wait their queue.

Comment: @Ivan Kishchenko: `Task`s a better choice in the context then `Thread`s (Task Manager shows threads, however). But why creating that many tasks and let them wait in a queue?

Comment: Task Manager show processes, but no threads! Any process can contains one or more threads! You are what is confusing. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Ivan Kishchenko: Ah, I see, I haven't used *standard* Task Manager for ages, it seems it doesn't provide many details such as threads, core object handles, HWNDs etc. I'm sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

The straight forward answer would be create them where you need them and start them there:

```
for (int j = 0; j < RowCount - 1; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < ColumnCount - 1; k++)
    {
        GridCell currentCell = GetCurrentCell (Slice1, Slice2, j, k);
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(()=>
        Polygonise (ref Triangles, isoLevel, currentCell));
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't know what `Triangles` is and how you might change it in your method , so it might be not wise to allow many Threads to change the same variable in an unordered fashion.

Comment: It's just a one thread for a one loop's passage, isn't it?
P.S. Triangles are for cells. They're independent too. It's ok.

Comment: @JuliaGrabovska Yes for each iteration it creates a thread. Which is a lot if you have a big matrix. Whether this really is an improvement I cannot say. You would have to measure the performance yourself. In the end you will have (RowCount - 1) * (ColumnCount - 1) Threads

Answer (score -1):

You can use collection of Tasks.
It's best alternative of threads.

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int j = 0; j < RowCount - 1; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < ColumnCount - 1; k++)
            {
                GridCell currentCell = GetCurrentCell(Slice1, Slice2, j, k);

                // Start a new Task and add it to collection
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
                {
                    Polygonise(ref Triangles, isoLevel, currentCell);
                }));
            }
        }

        // Waiting for the completion of all tasks
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

But you have to be careful. Capture of variables does not always work the way you expect it. ([Literature](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/88e68dfe-5ca0-46e0-83fa-0038f624d04f/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot?forum=csharpgeneral))

Comment: If you suggest `Task` implementation, you, probably, mean `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` in order not to block UI (the main advantage of using `Task`s)

Comment: Could be so. It depends of implementation.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` should be avoided, `Task.Run`. see http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html for dfetailes